# Cocoa bindings - getting "deallocated while key value observers were still registered" warnings

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have been using Cocoa bindings in my NSTableCellView inside my NSOutlineView, but supplying my own data into the `outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` method (i.e. not using an NSArrayController for the content). It works fine, till I delete a row from the table, where I get the managed object and delete it from the context, and in the NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification observer, I update my data model and remove the row from the outlineView. But when I do this, I get this warning:

> An instance 0x10d922890 of class Log_Log_ was deallocated while key
>   value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was
>   leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object.
>   Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger.
>   Here's the current observation info ....

Setting the breakpoint doesn't really help identify the problem. I know something is observing the properties on Log (the tableCellView that is doing the binding) but how do I clean it up when the row is removed from the outline view? I override Log's `didTurnIntoFault` and I do get a non-nil value in self.observationInfo, but I don't think that can help identify what is the observing object that needs to be removed as an observer at this point. 
I'm not sure why this is happening, and what is the best way to debug this to find the offending object that is the 'bindings' observer.

Answer (score 1):

NSTableCellViews are saved for reuse, so your zombie-esque cellView is holding onto the objectValue.  When you delete the row, you might want to nil out the objectValue in the cellviews.

Might make sense to use the NSTableViewDelegate didRemoveRowView:forRow for this.

Comment: Doesn't help, still crashing

Comment: @Julian try an explicit `unbind` before setting to nil.  Similar to what is suggested at the [bottom of the page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlContent.html).  If that works for you, I'll update this "answer."  What needs to be unbound might depend on your code.

Comment: I found out I had a memory issue as well, so the solution was kinda hidden. Worked now, thanks